# Securely set date that user can't manipulate react-native

Tags: react-native

Building a simple application which restricts usage based on the date. For example, you can only view a page 3 times per day.

However, if I use the device time, users can change their time and then view these pages again.

Is there another best practice method of doing so? Trying to avoid a call to the server. Using react-native. Thanks

Comment: "Never trust the client." It's always advised to use the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kinda tricky without hitting the server.

**into**

Let's assume that the first time they open your app the user date is correct. (I really don't know any other way checking that in an offline way)

That moment we need to save the current timestamp to the localstorage (called AsyncStorafe in RN).

**solution**

The only way you can really be sure that the timestamp is correct is keep a task that counts every seconds/minute/hours, whatever is logical in your situation.

**issue**

Doing this in react native won't get you that far, but we are able to make a Java background service for example that we start as soon as the app closes. Here you should keep up with the time and save this when the app launches to a place where it's also accessible from react native (not sure if AsyncStorage is).

**Info**

Here you can find some information about bavkground tasks in RN: https://hackernoon.com/easy-os-background-tasks-in-react-native-bc4476c48b8a?source=linkShare-cdf0b7d5ccb4-1538965801

The most secure amd easy way of time cheat prevention is by hitting the server vut if that's not a possibility that this may be a interesting way to still check it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is only use server time.
you can use following lib

https://github.com/artem-russkikh/react-native-clock-sync